# React Native Axios JavaScript how to pass an array of strings as params in GET requrest

Tags: javascript, react-native, api, get, axios

I am using the Axios for API calls, I need to send an array of strings in a `GET Request` how can I add my list in params(in URL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.get('/api', {
    params: {
      data: JSON.stringify(data)
    }
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
```

Comment: or also `const response = await axios.get('/api', { ... });`